# How do I acquire bike network shapefiles for a particular region?

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, openstreetmap

I'm working on a bike project that spans a number of cities in a region. Some of the cities have their existing bike infrastructure available as open data, but not all.

Is there a way to extract from OpenStreetMap or some other source only the bike infrastructure network, which preferably has a breakdown of facility type (sharrow, bike lane, protected bike lane).

Comment: It definitely seems like openstreetmap is the way to go, given their extensive rules on tagging bike infrastructure https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bicycle
I still need to figure out to download/extract only bike infrastructure though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; go to [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) and build your query based on `cycleway` tags. It's not guaranteed that OSM will have official open data in it, as manual collection and addition always takes priority over imports.

You might also want to ask on [OpenStreetMap Help Forum](https://help.openstreetmap.org/).